# Aspect orientated programming and Enterprise Library logging

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, aop

We use Enterprise Library Logging block for logging (what else :) )

Is it possible to use AOP to log a trace entry to and trace exist from all methods (with values of parameters) without manually adding a call to entlib as we do today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Policy Injection Application Block and the Logging Handler.
See more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664572(PandP.50).aspx
and the Interception Lab 10 from the [Hands-On Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4f8cd377-5522-4f45-a024-44a6ca5111ec&displaylang=en).